# How to remove white space at the end of an Rmarkdown HTML output

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a common culprit for white space at the end of a markdown? Here's what the end of my HTML output looks like. And my options:

````
```
{r }
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6, fig.asp=.618, fig.align="center",
fig.path='Figs/', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, cache=TRUE)
```
````

[image]

While I do not have a reprex handy, I did try several reruns, and found that the YAML is causing the white space, specifically the `toc_float: true`.

```
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %d %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: textmate
    code_folding: show
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: inline
always_allow_html: yes
```

Edit: Here's a reproducible example:

````
---
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B, %d %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: textmate
    code_folding: show
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: inline
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: @tarleb I typically make reprex's with my questions. This question seemed a little different, given it's the rendering of a HTML with knitr. I tried to provide what is potentially necessary to answer the question. I'll see if I can work up a minimal rmarkdown example. Thanks.

Comment: Thx! I was able to reproduce it and poked around a bit. Seems to be caused by the floating toc. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the [tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/) script included in HTML output. The script is included if `toc_float` is set to `true` (or if it contains more options).

The option to add the white space is configurable in principle through the tocify `extendOffset` option.  However, it appears that R Markdown does not expose a way to set the option through YAML. Currently, the only way to get rid of it is to unset `toc_float`.

Comment: Thank you! "However, it appears that R Markdown does expose a way to set the option through YAML." Did you mean "does not expose?"

Comment: Oops, yes, bad typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

According to https://community.rstudio.com/t/floating-table-of-contents-and-plots-produce-extra-whitespace-at-bottom/12606/8 you can keep `toc_float` and remove the extra white space by inserting the following html code at the bottom of the .Rmd file:

```
<div class="tocify-extend-page" data-unique="tocify-extend-page" style="height: 0;"></div>
```

Worked for me!

Comment: This fixed the problem for me as well. Seems like this should be the accepted answer.